# Magento 2.1.8 Authorize.net payment method not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, authorize.net

Magento 2.1.8, Authorized.net payment method is not working, even with signature key. It was working fine before with patch installed.

[image]

I got error at checkout page **The Referrer or Relay Response URL is invalid**.

**Note: Do we need to upgrade for client key or not**.

Please give me any suggestions or else.

Your help would be appreciated.!!! Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolved this issue, please try Magento marketplace below extension which made by Authorize.Net:

https://marketplace.magento.com/authorizenet-magento-module-authorizenet.html

If you getting any issue then check the compatible version and upgrade accordingly which can be help your problem.

Thanks
Ketan T.

Comment: This is not working. Downloaded folder comes with only composer.json file.

After running command 
composer require authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet

Error: 
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a
   stability which matches your minimum-stability (alpha).

Comment: If you are facing issue with this then please try to install extension on any fresh setup and then copy all configured setting from upgrade setup files to your required setup. Composer folder files stores configuration about composer modules settings.

Feel free to ask anything if you face any issue.

Hope this can be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable information. I will try this solution.

Thanks